# My first Ant-Subversion Bamboo plan

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, bamboo

I am playing with Bamboo to learn it, but I still can't build a very stupid plan for a Java web application hosted on SVN (we haven't *yet* migrated to Git).

Our company currently owns two multi-project SVN repositories

```
http://svn.server/svnroot/products
http://svn.server/svnroot/platform
```

Both contain multiple project.

Let's say I want to build `http://svn.server/svnroot/platform/trunk/projectA` which has an Ant build.xml file

I don't completely understand how to configure Bamboo to download the source code from that project in that repository. I mean, I have already configured the two repositories globally and can select them in my brand new build plan.

But I can't specify a directory. It is my understanding that Bamboo is likely to download the whole repository instead of the directory of my interest.

I could try (and I am actually) to define a new repository with direct path, but I don't like the idea of defining a repository for each build (including specifying the credentials).

Am I missing something? I can't find guidance on configuring SVN checkout in Bamboo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're right, when you define SVN repository you should set full path to folders you want to checkout. Then if you have several projects on same folder and you want to checkout them independently - you should create as many repos as projects you have.

Comment: Time to accelerate on Bitbucket migration, then :-(

Comment: It has the same logic, you can't checkout part of Git repo

Comment: Uhm... yes but in Git you will have one repo per project, while often in SVN you have a multi-project repository. Downloading all the code files for the current project is what I like Bamboo to do

Comment: I mean there is no good solution for your initial question. You will have separate repository for each project in SVN and in the same separate repository in Git